# Reading values within pandas.groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below

```
    name    item 
0   Jack    A
1   Sarah   B
2   Ross    A
3   Sean    C
4   Jack    C
5   Ross    B
```

What I like to do is to produce a dictionary that connects people to the products they are related to.

```
{Jack: [1, 0, 1], Sarah: [0, 1, 0], Ross:[1, 1, 0], Sean:[0, 0, 1]}
```

I feel like this should be done fairly easily using pandas.groupby

I have tried looping through the dataframe, but I have >1E7 entries, and  looping does not look very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `crosstab` and `to_dict`

```
pd.crosstab(df.item,df.name).to_dict('l')
{'Jack': [1, 0, 1], 'Ross': [1, 1, 0], 'Sarah': [0, 1, 0], 'Sean': [0, 0, 1]}
```

---

Another interesting option is using `str.get_dummies`:

```
# if you need counts 
df.set_index('item')['name'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).to_dict('l')
# if you want to record boolean indicators 
df.set_index('item')['name'].str.get_dummies().max(level=0).to_dict('l')
# {'Jack': [1, 0, 1], 'Ross': [1, 1, 0], 'Sarah': [0, 1, 0], 'Sean': [0, 0, 1]}
```